# Must have non-null value for 'Binding' problem

Tags: c#, wpf, binding

I have made a custom Control in WPF which is a star rating. When there are 5 stars, these should be golden.

```xml
<UserControl x:Class="Lama.Wpf.Controls.RatingControl"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
             xmlns:controls="clr-namespace:Lama.Wpf.Controls"
             mc:Ignorable="d">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.Resources>
            <ControlTemplate x:Key="RatingTemplate" TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}">
                <Viewbox>
                    <Path Name="star" Fill="White" Opacity="0.2"
                          Data="F1 M 145.637,174.227L 127.619,110.39L 180.809,70.7577L 114.528,68.1664L 93.2725,5.33333L 70.3262,67.569L 4,68.3681L 56.0988,109.423L 36.3629,172.75L 91.508,135.888L 145.637,174.227 Z" />
                </Viewbox>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <MultiDataTrigger>
                        <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                            <Condition Property="IsChecked" Value="True" />
                            <Condition
                                Binding="{Binding Rating, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=controls:RatingControl}}"
                                Value="5" />
                        </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                        <MultiDataTrigger.Setters>
                            <Setter TargetName="star" Property="Fill" Value="Gold" />
                            <Setter TargetName="star" Property="Opacity" Value="1" />
                        </MultiDataTrigger.Setters>
                    </MultiDataTrigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Grid.Resources>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition />
            <ColumnDefinition />
            <ColumnDefinition />
            <ColumnDefinition />
            <ColumnDefinition />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <ToggleButton Grid.Column="0" Tag="1" Padding="2" Template="{StaticResource RatingTemplate}"
                      Click="ClickEventHandler" />
        <ToggleButton Grid.Column="1" Tag="2" Padding="2" Template="{StaticResource RatingTemplate}"
                      Click="ClickEventHandler" />
        <ToggleButton Grid.Column="2" Tag="3" Padding="2" Template="{StaticResource RatingTemplate}"
                      Click="ClickEventHandler" />
        <ToggleButton Grid.Column="3" Tag="4" Padding="2" Template="{StaticResource RatingTemplate}"
                      Click="ClickEventHandler" />
        <ToggleButton Grid.Column="4" Tag="5" Padding="2" Template="{StaticResource RatingTemplate}"
                      Click="ClickEventHandler" />

    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

```cs
public partial class RatingControl
{
   private const int Max = 5;

   public static readonly DependencyProperty RatingProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(nameof(Rating),
       typeof(int),
       typeof(RatingControl),
       new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(0, FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.BindsTwoWayByDefault,
           RatingChanged));

   public int Rating
   {
      get => (int)GetValue(RatingProperty);
      set
      {
         if (value < 0)
         {
            SetValue(RatingProperty, 0);
         }
         else if (value > Max)
         {
            SetValue(RatingProperty, Max);
         }
         else
         {
            SetValue(RatingProperty, value);
         }
      }
   }

   public RatingControl()
   {
      InitializeComponent();
   }

   private static void RatingChanged(DependencyObject sender, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
   {
      var item = sender as RatingControl;
      var newVal = (int)e.NewValue;
      var children = ((Grid)(item.Content)).Children;

      ToggleButton button;

      for (var i = 0; i < newVal; i++)
      {
         button = children[i] as ToggleButton;
         if (button != null)
            button.IsChecked = true;
      }

      for (var i = newVal; i < children.Count; i++)
      {
         button = children[i] as ToggleButton;
         if (button != null)
            button.IsChecked = false;
      }
   }

   private void ClickEventHandler(object sender, RoutedEventArgs args)
   {
      var button = sender as ToggleButton;

      if (button == null)
      {
         return;
      }

      var newValue = int.Parse(button.Tag.ToString());
      Rating = newValue;
   }
}
```

If I run this, I get this exception:

> InvalidOperationException: Must have non-null value for 'Binding'.

Do I bind something wrong inside my condition? Because if I remove the `Rating`-Binding, it works, but I don't see my mistake here.

Comment: Be aware that the Rating property setter will not be called when you set the property in XAML, e.g. by a Binding like `<local:RatingControl Rating="{Binding SomeProperty}"/>`. WPF bypasses the setter and calls `SetValue` directly. You must therefore not have anything else in the setter than `SetValue(RatingProperty, value);`

Comment: Yes, you are right, I should write this code inside the dependencyproperty

Comment: No, the code from the property setter should be inside a coerce callback. Here you can modify the current value before it is finally passed to the property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple issues in your `Condition` bindings:

- The first binding in the `MultiDataTrigger` uses a `Condition` that sets `Property`, [which is wrong](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.multidatatrigger.conditions?view=net-5.0#remarks).

  > For a MultiDataTrigger, each condition in the collection must set both the Binding and Value properties. For more information, see Binding.

  Set the `Binding` property using a `RelativeSource` binding to `Self` instead.

  ```
  <Condition Binding="{Binding IsChecked, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" Value="True"/>
  ```
- The second binding to `Rating` is faulty, since it would only ever set any star to be golden and opaque if the rating is exactly five stars. So no stars are selected for any other rating.

In order resolve these issues, you can use a simple `Trigger` on the `IsChecked` property.

```
<ControlTemplate.Triggers>
   <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="True">
      <Setter TargetName="star" Property="Fill" Value="Gold" />
      <Setter TargetName="star" Property="Opacity" Value="1" />
   </Trigger>
</ControlTemplate.Triggers>
```

If it is really your requirement to only make the stars golden and opaque if the rating is exactly `5`, then you could correct the `MultiDataTrigger` as stated above:

```
<ControlTemplate.Triggers>
   <MultiDataTrigger>
      <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
         <Condition Binding="{Binding IsChecked, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" Value="True"/>
         <Condition Binding="{Binding Rating, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=controls:RatingControl}}" Value="5"/>
      </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
      <MultiDataTrigger.Setters>
         <Setter TargetName="star" Property="Fill" Value="Gold" />
         <Setter TargetName="star" Property="Opacity" Value="1" />
      </MultiDataTrigger.Setters>
   </MultiDataTrigger>
</ControlTemplate.Triggers>
```

---

Another note on value coercion. As @Clemens stated in the comments, setting a property in XAML e.g. like below will bypass your setter and
call `SetValue` directly. Your setter should only call `SetValue` as the behavior will differ otherwise when setting properties in XAML or through the property.

```
<local:RatingControl Rating="{Binding SomeProperty}"/>
```

Instead of the checks in the setter, you can specify a value coercion callback in the dependency property declaration.

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty RatingProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
   nameof(Rating), typeof(int), typeof(RatingControl), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(
      0, FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.BindsTwoWayByDefault, RatingChanged, CoerceRating));
```

Then create a `CoerceRating` method that contains your checks and returns the corresponding values.

```
private static object CoerceRating(DependencyObject d, object baseValue)
{
   var value = (int)baseValue;

   if (value < 0)
   {
      return 0;
   }

   if (value > Max)
   {
      return Max;
   }

   return value;
}
```

Finally, remove all checks from the setter of `Rating`.

```
public int Rating
{
   get => (int)GetValue(RatingProperty);
   set => SetValue(RatingProperty, value);
}
```

The value coercion callback will automatically be called, when the property is set through `SetValue` and therefore ensure that the `Rating` value is within the valid interval.

Comment: Okay now I see, thank you a lot! One of the best answers ever saw on SO. Also thanks for showing how to use the coerceValueCallback.